# Controlling the plot range of a PairedBarChart

Tags: plotting

I would like to adjust the plot range of a PairedBarChart along the 'bar' direction. However,

```
PairedBarChart[RandomReal[10, 10], RandomReal[10, 10], 
  PlotRange -> 
    {{0, 20} (*along bar/ labeled axis*), 
     Automatic (*along center axis*)}]
```

doesnt work.

Comment: This was in Version 9; Version 10 works, see below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It functions with **V10**:

```
PairedBarChart[RandomReal[10, 10], RandomReal[10, 10],
 PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, Automatic}]
```

[image]

The same with **V9** delivers an error message. Replacing `Automatic` with `All` in **V9** functions, but doesn't produce the desired result:

```
PairedBarChart[data1, data2, PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, All}]
```

[image]